# Installing angular/core peer dependency

Tags: angular

I recently have tried Angular 9.0.0-rc.7, but as a result are am seeing a lot of messages to install the peer dependencies of earlier Angular versions, for example:

```
primeng@9.0.0-rc.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Usually for a peer dependency, I would do a command such as:

```
npm install <package> --save
```

However, do I really want to do that if it's major angular components like angular/core?  Will that just increase the size of the build?

Answer (score 1):

The modules required for development of you application are used for development phase only. If you have module with size 10MB that does not mean it will get in build.

The size of build is totally dependent on how many `imports` have you used. If you check currently your `node_modules` folder will be more than 200MB, but after building angular project, the `dist` directory will be just in few `MB`.

You can have any number of dependencies in `node_modules`, as long as you are not using them, it wont take space in build.

Comment: You can post the answer, if it adds something to the discussion, it will definitely help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take the relevent `primeng` verions instead that matches the angular version you are using? I assume your angular `core` modules are fairly lower. But the version of primeng you are trying to use is a release candidate version`(primeng@9.0.0-rc.2)` which is newer than your angular version. If you pick the relevent primeng version which matches your version you dont want to go through installing peer dependencies. Also agreeing to the what @Plochie said above. You can consider this going forward to use the primeng version that matches your project.